# adding a try catch around a large method call

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web service that's pretty simple; something like this:

```
public class LeadService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string MyService(string TheIncomingData)
    {
             string ReturnData = "";

             MyClass TheClass = new MyClass();
             ReturnData = TheClass.MyMethod(TheIncomingData);

             return ReturnData;
        }
}
```

You might have guessed it, the MyMethod is a pretty long-running method with some room for errors (for now). If I add a try/catch statement around the method call like this:

```
try { ReturnData = TheClass.MyMethod(TheIncomingData); }
catch { ReturnData = ""; }
```

Is this going to make the service and the app exception-proof? And, is using a try statement like this going to have any performance impact even if no error occurs?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Swallowing exceptions like this is a _bad_ idea. You need to know why things break when they do.

Comment: @Oded: I agree with you but for the moment I'm looking to see how I can make the app not break in front of future users.

Comment: You can't possibly foresee all reasons something like this will break. What happens if the datacentre has a power failure? How will your application resilient to that? Don't over complicate things.

Comment: @Oded: in the catch statement, is there a way to know which line of code in the MyMethod threw the exception? Note the MyMethod also creates instances of other objects that run their methods too.

Comment: You can catch _specific_ exceptions. And if you deploy with symbols (pdb files), you should be able to get the file and line that threw the exception (using the StackTrace and frames).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is using a `try` statement like this going to have any performance impact even if no error occurs?

No.

Is the application exception-proof?

Yes. However if you have `onApplicationError` event in the `Global.asax` you won't be able to see the error since you are not throwing a new one.

But the way I see it for now, your code is safe from exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this going to make the service and the app exception-proof?

Yes, it seems that's the only place where exception can raise. So you will catch every exception using this try catch

> And, is using a try statement like this going to have any performance impact even if no error occurs?

No, it won't cause any performance issue in case of no error

On the side note it is not a good practise to just ignore the exception like this. May be you can return a customized error to user so that user can do something instead of just wondering why I am getting back a empty string

Comment: Unless the `MyClass` constructor throws.

Comment: Yup, that's right but generally speaking there are slim chances of that

Answer (score 1):

That's a way to make the app "exception-proof", yes, at least when seen by a client. But it won't make it **error-proof**, and it will make it **harder** to find an error whenever your client gets an empty string.

If you are willing to accept the risk of swallowing exceptions and potentially leaving your application in an undefined state, you could **at least** return the exception info as the result so that someone can understand what really happened. If there was an unanticipated input, you must inform your clients and log the error for yourself.

- Did your client enter invalid input data? Do you know which data it was, and how to repeat the problem?
- Did it happen with valid data? Where and how did it happen?

A much better solution would be to add the `Application_Error` handler method in your `Global.ashx` file, log the exception (possibly notifying the admin by e-mail when this happens), and use a custom error page for your users.

This article explains it well: [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5977/Global-Error-Handling-in-ASP-NET).

Answer (score 1):

Is it exception proof? Yes.  Will it hurt performance? Not as far as the execution of this code block is concerned.  However, I suggest you rewrite the code so that it allows you to handle the exception and get the desired result:

```
public class LeadService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string MyService(string TheIncomingData)
{
         MyClass TheClass = new MyClass();
         try{
            return TheClass.MyMethod(TheIncomingData);
         }
         catch(Exception ex){
            //handle your exception, log, etc.
         }                
        return "";                 
    }
```

}